# ASP.NET core get route data values into input box

Tags: controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a razor view in which a person's information are displayed, it route is `https://localhost:PORT/Pesron/Details/E-12345`.

I want to create a profile for the said person using another controller, the corresponding link would be `https://localhost:PORT/Profile/Create/E-12345`.

The page would open normally, but I would like getting the value `E-123456` which is the person's ID and obviously changes from one to another, into a (disabled) input box in `Create`, so when I fill other information and press submit, a new profile is created, I am doing it using MVC controller but wouldn't mind using Web API too.
How I open `Create` in `Person`'s `Details` view.

`<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Profile" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">Create</a>`

My 2 `Create` action methods.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string MRN, [Bind("Id,Dep_Id,Check_In,Check_Out")] Profile profile)
        {
            ViewData["ID"] = MRN;


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(profile);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }


            return View(profile);
        }
```

```
        public IActionResult Create(string MRN)
        {
           ViewData["ID"] = MRN;

            return View();
        }
```

Could the reason be that the value I am sending is not the primary key, I made it hidden and auto incrementing.

Comment: Hi ,any update about this case?If it doesn't work,you can provide your code.

Comment: You should use `asp-route-MRN="@Model.ID"`. Change your code to `<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Profile" asp-route-MRN="@Model.ID">Create</a>`

Comment: Does putting MRN in the `Bind()` have anything to do with it?

Comment: You don't need to put MRN in the Bind().You can have a try.

Comment: Removing Bind() is solving the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewData`.Below is an example.

View:

```
<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Profile" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">Create</a>
```

Create action:

```
 public IActionResult Create(string id)
    {
        ViewData["ID"] = id;

        return View();
    }
```

Create View:

```
 <input value="@ViewBag.ID" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Post Create method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Profile profile, string id)
    {
        //.....
        return RedirectToAction("actionname","Controllername");
    }
```

Comment: Not working, also trying @ViewData["ID"], not working too.

Comment: Where does it not work? Is the correct id not displayed in the input box?

Comment: Yes, the input box is blank.

Comment: Hit a breakpoint in your Create action, observe whether the id is successfully bound, and make sure that `<input value="@ViewBag.ID" disabled="disabled"/>` is in your Profile/Create view.

Comment: You can see my [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSULd.gif).